# search database with ajax and codeIgniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, search

I wana make search but i get repetative results, how to delete prev code form prev ajax request my code in ajax is:

```
<script>
$(function () {


    $("#sample_search").keyup(function () {
        var that = this,
        value = $(this).val();


            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "<?php echo site_url('home/search')?>",
                data: {
                    'search_keyword' : value
                },
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(msg){
                    //we need to check if the value is the same
                    $("#prostor").append("<p id='rezultati'>"+msg+"</p>");
                }
            });

    });
}); 


</script>
```

and in php

```
 public function search(){
        if(isset($_post['search_keyword'])){

            $var = $_post['search_keyword'];
            $q = $this->db->query("SELECT * from users where username like '%{$var}%'");
            foreach ($q ->result() as $a){
                echo $a->username;
            }

        }
    }
```

My question is how to remove prev search result

Comment: "repetative code" what you mean by this  ? Please specify your required output and current output.

Comment: i mean repatavive results for example if i type b then i ,i will get result of billbill

Comment: Is `$_post['search_keyword']`(small `$_post`) working for you?

Comment: For preventing repetition of results use `html()` instead of `append()` in your jquery code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `html()` instead of `append()` in `$.ajax` call, like below

```
success: function(msg){
 //we need to check if the value is the same
 $("#prostor p#rezultati").html(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the problem in here:

```
$("#prostor").append("<p id='rezultati'>"+msg+"</p>");
```

Problem: You repeatedly append paragraphs with the same `id`, but with different content to `prostor`. It is enough to have the `<p>` tag inside `prostor` from the start and then always change its `text`/`html` using the `.text()`/`.html()` functions.

Comment: tnx correct i give bonus to guy upper because he first reply